# Dart convert Map<Object,Object> to Map<String,Object>

Tags: dart

I have a class on type Map(Object,Object) where I know the keys are all strings.  How can I easily convert it to a Map(String,Object)?

Specifically the object is coming from a Firestore query

```
Firestore.instance.collection('schedule').document('nfl-2018').snapshots().data.data
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a number of ways to convert or wrap the map.
The two primary ones are the [`Map.cast` method](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.68.0/dart-core/Map/cast.html) and the [`Map.from` constructor](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.68.0/dart-core/Map/Map.from.html).

```
Map<Object, Object> original = ...;
Map<String, Object> wrapped = original.cast<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> newMap = Map<String, Object>.from(first);
```

The `wrapped` map created by `Map.cast` is a wrapper around the original map. If the original map changes, so does `wrapped`. It is simple to use but comes with an extra type check on every access (because the wrapper checks the types at run-time, and it has to check every time because the original map may have changed). 
The map created by `Map.from` is a new map, which means all the data from the original map are copied and type checked when the map is created, but afterwards it's a separate map that is not connected to the original.

Answer (score 6):

`Map.from` ([doc here](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.67.0/dart-core/Map/Map.from.html)) seems to work fine as a way to convert maps. As noted by lrn in comments below, this creates a *new* Map copy of the desired type. It doesn't cast the existing map.

```
  final Map<Object, Object> first = <Object, Object>{'a': 'test!', 'b': 1};
  final Map<String, Object> second = Map<String, Object>.from(first);
```

You can try it out in DartPad [here](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/bf5c0641c91b6cf4cd0a63cc09c87b8a)!

Comment: Wow adding a link to pre-written code is convenient! I'm definitely gonna do that from now on.

Comment: There are many different ways to convert a map, including wrapping the original by doing `first.cast<String, Object>()`, but the `from` method here is the correct choice if you want to create a *new* map.

Comment: @lrn I didn't know about `cast`, that seems worthy of an answer!